# Help with sequential numbering in a Entries loop?

Tags: channel-entries, jquery

I'm trying to get my head around EE so please bear with me on something probably simple:

How do you loop through a EE entries chunk and append a number? Like a id="blogitem-1", id="blogitem-2", id="blogitem-3"... there may be no end to the numbering.

I have a blog section that requires each hidden ID be sequential. I got the jquery popover working using {entry_id} but I need to go forwards and backwards and the pager doesn't work. I cheated a little using {switch="1|2|3|4"}... but that's really ugly and it has a fixed end.

Here's the code snippet:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    status="Open"
    dynamic="no"
    paginate="bottom"                
}
<!-- This is a blog item -->
<div class="blogitem-content hidden" id="blogitem-{entry_id}">
    <img src="{base_image:blogimg}" alt="{title}">
    <h2 class="primary-color">{title}</h2>
    <h3>{subtitle}</h3>
    {body}              

    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous"><a href="#blogitem-2" class="">&larr; Previous</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#blogitem-4" class="">Next &rarr;</a></li>
    </ul>              

</div>
<!-- / Blog item -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This shows what could be entry #3, with the pager linking to the previous id (#2) and the next (#4). While "{entry_id}" lets me pop-up the post, I can't navigate.

I also don't want to expose PHP to the template (not understanding PHP too much I don't want to open up something that can bite me later). I can't seem to generate a simple progressive 1, 2, 3... for the id.

I'm learning EE and a bit of jQuery, so sorry if this is elementary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [{count}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#count) or [{absolute_count}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#absolute-count), instead of {entry_id}. {count} restart on every page, while {absolute_count} increases across pagination.

By the way, 'tackbacks' isn't a value of the [disable parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#disable).

Comment: Thanks!

I tried {count} before but I must have done something wrong - much appreciated. On trackbacks, I'm using a EE styling plugin for Textmate and it was a default on expansion - maybe a holdover from EE1? 

Now all I need to do is figure out how to do math and increment up and down 1 record for the pager…

Comment: As a point, I found a [math plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math) to do the incrementing-decrementing.

Comment: If all the ID numbers are sequential, I really don't see any reason for you to worry about the IDs of the pagers. Is really easy to do the math and find them.

Comment: Do the math on JS, I mean!

Comment: Actually, the id's aren't sequential as they're coming from a field using the new relationship tool, and the user is setting the order themselves. I used "blog" only as an example. 


@Robert - again, early days, but I wanted to do things within each embed